# How to remove `case of` from this code?

Tags: haskell

How do I rewrite the following code, so that it:

1. uses less characters
2. contains at most one `case ... of ...`

```
-- parseSQL :: String -> Either ParseError SQL
-- evalSQL :: SQL -> IO (Either EvalError Table)
-- prettyPrintTable :: Table -> IO ()
-- ParseError, EvalError and Table are instances of Show

evalAndPrint :: String -> IO ()
evalAndPrint x =
    case parseSQL x of
      (Left parseErr) ->
        print parseErr
      (Right sql) -> do
        result <- evalSQL sql
        case result of
          (Left err) ->
            print err
          (Right table) -> do
            prettyPrintTable table
            putStrLn $ "(" ++ show (length table) ++ " lines)\n"
```

Comment: Looks like a perfect candidate for `ErrorT`, `EitherT` or some other error monad transformer.

Comment: You can *almost* do this directly using the `Monad` instance for `Either`. Unfortunately, `evalSQL` kind of messes that up. So it looks like you'll need `EitherT` or something...

Comment: It's also difficult because the Either monad instances used are different in each case. The first Either monad instance is `Either ParseError` and the second is `Either EvalError`.

Answer (score 3):

For the moment, let's assume you've generalized your `parseSQL` and `evalSQL` functions to have these types (later we'll see how to turn your specialized implementations into generalized ones even if you don't have access to their source):

```
parseSQL :: MonadError ParseError m => String -> m SQL
evalSQL :: (MonadError EvalError m, MonadIO m) => SQL -> m Table
```

Then we can write:

```
-- if we were really doing this the mtl way, we'd introduce a new
-- type class for changing error types instead of specializing to
-- ExceptT, but that's another answer
evalAndThrow :: String -> ExceptT String IO ()
evalAndThrow s = do
    sql   <- withExceptT show (parseSQL s)
    table <- withExceptT show (evalSQL sql)
    liftIO $ prettyPrintTable table
    liftIO . putStrLn $ "(" ++ show (length table) ++ " lines)\n"
```

The top-level function can then be something like

```
evalAndPrint s = do
    v <- runExceptT (evalAndThrow s)
    case v of
        Left err -> putStrLn err
        Right _  -> return ()
```

Here are some tricks for converting your existing functions into the mtl-style polymorphic versions. Either you can change their source directly, or you can make adapters using combinators like these:

```
-- this is a generally useful combinator
liftEither :: MonadError e m => Either e a -> m a
liftEither = either throwError return

-- this is a combinator specific to your question
liftIOEither :: (MonadError e m, MonadIO m) => IO (Either e a) -> m a
liftIOEither = join . liftIO . liftM liftEither
```

And of course there is also `ExceptT :: IO (Either e a) -> ExceptT e IO a`; `ExceptT . evalSQL` is not quite as polymorphic as `liftIOEither . evalSQL`, but since we're using it at the `ExceptT` type it may not matter in this case.